# How can I add/remove a class from the .editor-container in a quill instance

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm trying to show and hide specific styling based on user interaction. Ideally the styling markup for all the text wouldn't need to be changed whenever the user interaction changes. Is it possible to toggle a class on the editor-container inside the quill iFrame? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor has an instance variable root that is the container inside the iframe.

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor');
quill.root.classList.add('active');
```